# Get the ID of a new entry when it's saved

Tags: form, entry, redirect

Is there a way to save a new entry with a template form, then pass the ID of that new entry along to the redirect location?

The use case is, I'm interacting with a scheduling service and want to pass along the new craft entry ID in a query string to their API. The service has a webhook that fires on successful scheduling (and provides an appointment ID).

Currently, I'm getting the user's email address returned from the API, then *assuming* that user's most recent section/entry in craft is the one I'm looking for. After that, I can unambiguously handle reschedules and cancellations by referencing the appointment ID.

The form has the following inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/schedule">
```

and I'd like the /schedule page to get a entryId passed into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to do this without having to write your own plugin, you can achieve this with a simple custom route and an extra parameter in your template.

Your hidden fields could look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="schedule/{id}">
```

And then in `config/routes.php` put

```
'schedule/(?P<id>\d+)' => 'scheduleTemplate',
```

When craft saves the entry, it will redirect you to `schedule` with the ID of the entry that was just saved as the last segment. The custom route will pick up any digit on the end of the url and assign it to a variable called `id` which you can then use in your templates.

**Some behind the scenes clearance, based on your comment**

No they aren't twig variables as the replacement is doing through php (although apparently you can use Twig tags).

When you save an entry the new entry object gets passed in `redirectToPostedUrl` which, if there is an object passed will call the function `renderObjectTemplate` in the templates service, this will swap out any `{single}` or `{{twig}}` tags with the appropriate attribute and you will get the finished URL returned.

Here are two links to the class reference so you can see what I mean.

[The `redirectToPostedUrl` function](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/BaseController#redirectToPostedUrl-detail)

[The `renderObjectTemplate` function](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#renderObjectTemplate-detail)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know you could pass along entry parameters with single curly brackets. Doesn't look like they're twig variables, so is this getting handled by Craft's saveEntry action?

Comment: @DavidRampersad I've edited my answer with a couple of details about how it works, would have been too long for a comment otherwise and could have been hard to read!

Answer (score 3):

In a [custom plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) you can hook into the [saveEntry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event:

```
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event)]
{

    $entry = $event->params['entry'];

    // GET ENTRY ID
    $entryId = $entry->id 

    // DO YOUR STUFF
    ...

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to limit the conditions where your event hook kicks in? I only want this to fire with a certain sectionId, if it's new, if it was posted by a certain form.

Comment: Not really, but there's no overhead using the craft->on() event binder method, and you can easily test for all of the things you mention inside the event handler.